# Jquery UI Slider, Slider Handle image problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have the following problem:
I've taken the example for the slider from the `Jquery UI` website (from here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/side-scroll.html), and need to modify it so that the slider's handle shows a different graphic, but I can't get things to show up properly.

It *should* be as simple as pointing the background: property in "`.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider-handle`" to my image, or at least I thought so.  The functionality is working properly, and clicking in the general area of the scroll bar and moving left and right will make things scroll just fine.  The problem is that no matter what I try I can't get any sort of image (or `CSS properties`, for that matter) to show up with regards to the scroll bar and its handle!

Here is a directory with the mock-up I've been working with: Edit: Well that's embarrasing, I posted a bad page.  More below.

I've searched through Stack Overflow's jquery UI threads, and googled in general, but I can't seem to hit upon a solution.  At this point I'm thinking that it's some simple CSS thing that's messing with me and making the handle invisible, but leaving the functionality intact.  Please, what am I doing wrong?

Edit: 
Ok, I apologize for posting a link to a page that wasn't showing the proper mockup.  Sorry for wasting anyones time.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding this class's in your css file.. Check if this works

```
.ui-state-default,.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
background:green url(slider.png) 50% 50% repeat-x !important;
}​
```